# Core usage of my Dell studio 1557

Tags: applet, dell, temperature, process

I've notices that the sensors-applet (that measures the temperatures of CPU) is giving me 4 measures and only 2 of theme seems to indicate the work temperatures.

[Here is the applet output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0pVTl.png). i'm running ubuntu 10.04 on a dell studio 1557.

is this possible that it has preformance issues with thei7-720QM Core?

Answer (score 1):

This happens in most Dell systems.  The system does not always use all 4 cores at once, the temperature of whichever cores are being used will fluctuate accordingly.  Subsequently, the CPU frequency will fluctuate accordingly as well, if you're using those applets.

This also occurs on the Dell Latitude E6500 laptops as well.

**EDIT**
It could also be two sensors are malfunctioning, in which case it would explain the discrepancy of over 20 degrees Celsius at the processor.